# How to work around exceeded INT_MAX levels without reducing parent nodes in bnlearn R library?

Tags: r, bayesian-networks, bnlearn

I have been trying to build a Bayesian Network based on a dataset using bnlearn library in R, but I've been receiving the error shown below.

Entered codes:

```
library(bnlearn)
bn.fit(dag, data = df, method = "bayes")
```

Received error:

> Error in .table(data[, c(node, parents), drop = FALSE], with.missing =
> !all(data.info$complete.nodes[c(node, : attempting to create a table
> with more than INT_MAX cells.

I would like to keep the existing parent nodes. I'm wondering if there's a workaround for this error?

Comment: There's unfortunately no way around it, and even if it were, it means the resulting model would be *very* large. I'm not familiar with `bnlearn` but you could perhaps try adjusting it to create smaller models.

Comment: This can happen when a CPT has too many levels. You can `debug` the learning to see what are the problem nodes. Do you have node s with a lot of levels or does a node have a lot of parents? You can constrain the number of parents a node has or add a prior giving a small probability of an edge again to constrain.